# How do I use getElementById on dynamically created inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, input, dynamic, getelementbyid

I'm having a some trouble getting the state of dynamically created checkboxes. I used the code below to add several checkboxes, with dynamic Id's, to the body.

```
var html = ...;
for(var i = 0; i < options.checkTextArray.length; i++)
{
    html +=
    `
        <label class="checkbox" [attr.for]="'myCheckboxId' + i">
            <input class="checkbox__input" type="checkbox" [name]="'myCheckboxName' + i" [id]="'myCheckboxId' + i">
            <div class="checkbox__box"></div>${options.checkTextArray[i]}: 
        </label>
        <br>
    `;
}
```

In another part of the code, I would like to get and/or set the state of the checkboxes but havent succeeded so far. I tried using the code below to achieve my goals, but "document.getElementById(...)" keeps returning "null".

```
var ckbStateBuffer = new Array();
var txtContenBuffer = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < options.checkTextArray.length; i++) {
    ckbStateBuffer.push(document.getElementById("'myCheckboxId' + i").checked);
}
```

As you can see, I'd like to save the checkbox states in an array and use it, to reset the new states to the old ones (for example when a button is pushed).

So how should I be adding the states to this buffer array? What am I doing wrong in the code above? Tried several other things but none of those worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found a solution. Apparently you can't use `getElementById(checkboxId)` to get the checkbox states. You have to create an array using `getElementsByTagName("input")` and afterwards itterate through this array while checking for inputs of the checkbox type.

```
var inputsArray = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var ckbStateBuffer = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{

    if(inputsArray[i].type == "checkbox")
    {

        ckbStateBuffer.push(inputsArray[i].checked);

    }

}
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Maximo40000/agL9opq6/

A big thanks to Jarred Parr!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just have a simple error in your code. What you're trying to do is something to the affect of:

```
id=myCheckboxName1
id=myCheckboxName2
id=myCheckboxName3
...
```

However, your code is not correct:

```
<input class="checkbox__input" type="checkbox" [name]="'myCheckboxName' + i" [id]="'myCheckboxId' + i">
```

It's interpreting the entire id as a string and not inserting the numeric value so it looks like this: `myCheckboxIdi`

Perhaps try the following:

```
var html = ...;
for(var i = 0; i < options.checkTextArray.length; i++)
{
    var checkboxId = `myCheckboxId${i}`;
    html +=
    `
        <label class="checkbox" [attr.for]=${checkboxId}>
            <input class="checkbox__input" type="checkbox" [name]=${checkboxId} [id]=${checkboxId}>
            <div class="checkbox__box"></div>${options.checkTextArray[i]}: 
        </label>
        <br>
    `;
}
```

Notice how the value is now inserted in the string via the template string? This should work, but I didn't run it so it may need some modification. Your new code for accessing would be something like:

```
var ckbStateBuffer = new Array();
var txtContenBuffer = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < options.checkTextArray.length; i++) {
    ckbStateBuffer.push(document.getElementById(`myCheckboxId${i}`).checked);
}
```

Something to this affect should fix your code. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Hi Jarred and thanks for your reply. The problem still remains. I think it might be due to the inputs not being initialized yet? Not sure how it works, as all excperience I have in JS is this project I'm working on. Here's a fiddle I just made with all my code: [https://jsfiddle.net/Maximo40000/uedfgt6m/](https://jsfiddle.net/Maximo40000/uedfgt6m/). It doesn't seem to work in fiddle though, not sure why. You're supposed to see a window pop up after you click the button.

Comment: From what I'm seeing here, none of the checkboxes are even being rendered. Perhaps try getting that working before you loop through the checked fields might be a good sanity check.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've got it working now, wasn't able to get the fiddle working correctly before (it's my first time using it). I got it working by putting the JS content in a script in HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/Maximo40000/uedfgt6m/28/. A window containing a few checkboxes etc. should be appearing after you click the "change" button. Note that the "OK" and "Cancel" buttons on the window aren't working. This is because their handlers currently contain the "getElementById"'s wich still return "null". (see lines 142 - 149 & 159 - 164)

Comment: The problem in your code is that you're still passing the variable `checkBoxId` as a string. Notice how in my example I use the template string? You put this whole thing into a variable but did not re apply the template to place the variable.

Here's what I did:
`<input class="checkbox__input" type="checkbox" [name]=checkBoxName [id]=${checkBoxId}>`

Here's what you did:
`<input class="checkbox__input" type="checkbox" [name]=checkBoxName [id]=checkBoxId>`

Do you notice the difference?

Comment: This was in part an error for me, I apologize for that. Updating  my answer.

Comment: Oh okay right. I changed it but it still gives the same error. I made a simplified version here: [https://jsfiddle.net/Maximo40000/agL9opq6/](https://jsfiddle.net/Maximo40000/agL9opq6/). Should have done this from the start, would have been way easier for you to see whats happening.

Comment: Changing the for loop to this:


for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        checkBoxId = `myCheckboxId${i}`;
        ckbStateBuffer.push(document.getElementById(checkBoxId).checked);

      }


fixed it.